# I am getting error while importing numpy library in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *
roll_no= array([101,102,103,104,105,106,107],int)
print(rol_no)
```

Error is :

```
PS C:\Users\Ashish\csv, pandas> & C:/Users/Ashish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/Ashish/csv, pandas/data.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in numpy.random.bit_generator
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\secrets.py", line 19, in <module>
    from random import SystemRandom
ImportError: cannot import name 'SystemRandom' from 'random' (c:\Users\Ashish\csv, pandas\random.py)
```

Comment: I didn't import random module then why am i getting random module error ??

Comment: A module you are importing requires it.

Comment: I have latest version of python (3.9.6) and numpy (1.21.0) but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

What is your numpy version? Use the latest one.

This is the issue with 1.17.3 and current version in 1.21.0

See the issue raised here.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16753
and
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14860

Current version has solve this error.

Comment: I see no evidence from those issues that the current version would behave any differently...

Comment: I have tried it on my own system and it works with the latest version. I have mentioned the issue to show that the problem was in older version. I'll say you to try with latest version before commenting here..

Comment: I'll say to you that if your evidence of the current version not having this error is that you tried it, you should mention that in the answer (and make sure to include which version you're running, because future readers won't necessarily know what was current at this time).